# 403 forbidden error during send JSON data with ajax

Tags: ajax, django

these are code snippet for sending json data with ajax.
you can show same code in the last postings.
I'm just follow the code.
But I got 403 error

jsonpost.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        selected = $("#mySelect option:selected").text()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/test/jsontest/',
            data: {
                   'fruit': selected,
                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                  },
            success: function(result) {
                    document.write(result)
                    }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ data }}
    <br>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="apple" selected >Select fruit</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^jsontest/$', views.JsonRead.as_view(), name='userTest'),
)
```

views.py

```
class JsonRead(View):
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request, 'MW_Etc/jsonpost.html')

    def post(self,request):
        print(request.body)
        data = request.body
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

After change the fruit value, I got the error.
How can I resolve this?
Any others good ways is good as well.

[image]

Comment: What is the full error? You appear to be doing a post request without a csrf token..

Comment: @Sayse here is full error. 

POST http://localhost:8000/test/jsontest/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)
m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ (index):9
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32267337/edit) button under your question to update it with new information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using post method you have to send csrf token in the form,same has to be done in the case of ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        selected = $("#mySelect option:selected").text()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/test/jsontest/',
            data: {
                   'fruit': selected,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                  },
            success: function(result) {
                    document.write(result)
                    }
    });
  });
});
```

try like this,this worked for me.

Comment: i got a new message. Uncaught ReferenceError: qvgZZDSkIVlnsKFZB2HV6BYPgrpPkIx3 is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):16m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: @Zeamous I have some change your suggestion. like this. 'fruit' : selected, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'. but result is same

Comment: i have reedited my code there was a mistake it should be csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'

Comment: Yeah, I know. but result is same.

Comment: clear your cache and try and post the complete error you are getting